# Scipy - Multiplying large sparse matrix causes segmentation fault?

Tags: python, numpy, segmentation-fault, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a CSR sparse matrix in scipy of size 444075 x 444075. I wish to multiply it by its transpose. However, when I do `m * m.T` it causes a `segmentation fault 11` error. Is this a memory issue, and if so, is there a way to allocate more memory to the program? Is there a clever workaround/hack using subroutines other routines from scipy to multiply a different way?

Comment: If it's a memory issue it should give a `MemoryError`, not a segfault. Can you post some code that reproduces the error? What version of scipy are you using?

Comment: The code is just `m*m.T`, and the matrix is `<444075x444075 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'with 3348026 stored elements in COOrdinate format>`. I'm using version 15.1.

Comment: Does the error only occur for a specific matrix, or can you reproduce it with a random matrix?

Comment: Could you add your scipy version to the question, please? I can't reproduce your segfault for a random sparse matrix of equivalent dimensions, density, dtype and format, using either scipy v0.13.3 or v0.16.0.dev0+d139f48.

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment, my version is 15.1. I tried creating a random sparse matrix using scipy's sparse.rand but segfaulted on that as well.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the end of your last comment. Could you add the code that you used to generate the random matrix to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Scipy uses 8 bytes per non-zero integer in a sparse csr_matrix. With 4GB of available memory, and a matrix size of 444075x444075, no more than 0.272243315% of the matrix elements may be non-zero.

While your original matrix may contain only 3348026 non-zero elements, keep in mind that multiplying the matrix with its transpose may yield a more densely populated resultant matrix.

If you are running your application from a unix shell, the segmentation fault may well be due to the process being out of memory. If you're running from python shell, however, you should get a `MemoryError`.

The memory available to python is determined by how much physical RAM and virtual memory the operating system has available. You can check how much memory is available with [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil): `print psutil.phymem_usage()`.

Comment: The percentage of nonzero elements is 0.0016977%. (Proportion is 3348026/197202605625). Seems low enough not to cause a memory error then; is this likely a segmentation fault? Does this mean something is wrong with the scipy implementation?

Comment: Although `m` might comfortably fit in memory, the size of `m * m.T` will depend heavily on the sparsity structure of `m`. For example, if `m` contains a single column of non-zeros, then `m * m.T` will be completely dense.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue, turns out this is a memory problem. I ran the operation on another machine and received a MemoryIssue (whereas my machine gives a segfault), and when given more memory it turns into a "negative dimensions not allowed error" a long way into it, which I presume is an integer overflow in the calculation.

Comment: I'm glad you resolved your problem, but it seems to me that the segfault is probably unrelated to the memory issue. It sounds like an integer index is overflowing somewhere and becoming negative. It would be helpful for future readers if you could post the code you used to reproduce the segfault as well as the full error message that you see. Were the versions of scipy on the two machines the same?